# How does the react know for which request we have to use proxy and for which we have to use frontend react server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I have a little confusion in configuring a proxy in the package.JSON file to make API requests by using relative paths in the frontend app. I just want to know, when I use axios to fetch from api:

```
const {data} = await axios.get("/api/products");
```

it uses the proxy to serve the API. But when I write URLs in Link tag (react-router):

```
<Link to="/cart"> Go to cart</Link>
```

it uses the localhost of the frontend app(not the proxy this time).
How does react know for which request we have to use proxy and for which we have to use frontend react server?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't know.

First, it checks if the URL exists and if it doesn't, it ask proxied URL.